# Are module bundlers required on server side applications?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, reactjs, webpack

I am completely new to the concept of module bundling as I've just started working on client side application in ReactJS so I was wondering that is such bundling such as webpack used for server side code too such as a Nodejs micro-service or Application?

And if yes then why is it required on server side code if the code is never going to load on browser?

Comment: You can use it to bundle server code. I've done it before because of an aversion to having a project with an express backend and when I publish it normal `npm install` would give me a bunch of front end deps which are already in my client bundle. It doesn't really matter it just feels gross to have a node_modules there when I could have two bundles. But it isn't totally painless either. Can def be done. Up to you if valuable.

Comment: You built a npm module or was it a web application backend?

Comment: I was talking about a web application backend.

Comment: Oh in that case I actually didn't understand your use case. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Gave webpack two configs: one for client, one for server, the dist directory then has everything needed to run the app. What are you missing?

Comment: **I publish it normal ```npm install``` would give me a bunch of front end deps which are already in my client bundle** I am missing this part.```npm install``` would install everything in ```package.json``` so if you had single bundle then there was redundancy in dependecies. So you split it into 2 bundles?

Comment: Yeah exactly. Without the server bundle node server would resolve its dependences through node_modules, which would contain contain front end modules as well; they'd be redundant there as they would already exist in the client bundle. With both server and client bundled there's no reason to have node_modules in the prod environment at all.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense now :D

Comment: Why do you want to create a server bundle?

Comment: Oh I don't that is what I asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is such bundling such as webpack used for server side code too such as a Nodejs micro-service or Application?

No. As you've noted yourself, Webpack only makes sense for code that's going to run in a browser.

Comment: I have not seen any scenarios where client side and server side code are combined, but is such practice followed and what do we do in such cases to  use webpack(or any other bundler)? And if so then do we tell webpack to bundle only specific code? e.g. : That is only bundle Angular code and not node code